# Webpack-dev-server handle proxy header

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, node-http-proxy, http-proxy-middleware, webpack-dev-middleware

I have an issue with webpack-dev-server when it proxys to my prod env. The production server sends me 'set-cookie' header but it is an array and I don't see it in dev-server's response in the browser.

Also, when I debug I see a lot of headers coming from the prod server, but I have not all of them in the browser. How to make webpack-dev-server to bypass all the headers as is.

Thanks.

Comment: Side comment: webpack-dev-server is not meant to be used in production. A better setup would be for prod server to serve the output of the React application build: in dev from webpack-dev-server (being a reverse proxy for  webpack-dev-server) and in prod from disk.

Comment: I don't use it for production, i need my local env to get data from production, i.e. for debugging, investigating and so on

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, headers should be automatically copied from the proxy response to the response sent to the browser by http-proxy-middleware. The default behavior of most proxy implementations is to forward headers.

But, you could intercept all of the responses from proxy with the headers and inspect/modify them.

```js
proxy: {
                "**": {
                    target: "http://localhost:8000", // Proxy to backend
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    secure: false,

                    // This handles responses
                    onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
                       
                        // Get all headers from proxy response and write them out to console
                        Object.keys(proxyRes.headers).forEach((key) => {
                            console.log(`${key}: ${proxyRes.headers[key]}`);
                        });
                    }
                },
```